# Redux-Toolkit query : I can't get the data that has already been uploaded. by selectFromResult

Tags: rtk-query

Create API

```
export const pollingRatesApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'pollingRates',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: configuredBaseURL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getRates: builder.query<RatesStreamLongPollingData, RatesStreamParams>({
      queryFn: async (arg) => await api.get(getRatesStreamUrl(arg)),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLazyGetRatesQuery, useGetRatesQuery } = pollingRatesApi;
```

Component A loads data

```
  const [getRates, result] = useLazyGetRatesQuery();

  const handleGetRates = async (params) => {
    await getRates({ ...params, pollingInterval: 1000 });
  };
```

Child component B trying to get already uploading data

```
  const [, { currentData, isLoading, data }] = useLazyGetRatesQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: ({ data, error, isLoading }) => ({
      data,
      error,
      isLoading,
    }),
    pollingInterval: 1000,
  });
```

in child compoenent data === undefined  all the time. why so?
I use useLazy****Query because I can only form a link for a query after a series of other queries.

An attempt to get data through a selector in Child Components also returns undefined

```
  const rRates = (state) => pollingRatesApi.endpoints.getRates.select()(state).data;
  console.log(useSelector(rRates));
```

Answer (score 1):

`getRates(undefined)` and `getRates(params)` are two distinct cache entries. They would only give you a shared result if `params` were `undefined`, otherwise they make two independent requests to the server.

You would probably have to share those `params` between the two components, either by storing them in the Redux state or passing them as props.

Also, please note that `getRates({ ...params, pollingInterval: 1000 });` will not set a pollingInterval.

You have to pass options into `useLazyGetRatesQuery`, not into the trigger function:

```
const [getRates, result] = useLazyGetRatesQuery({ pollingInterval: 1000 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get this data using selectors? I couldn't do it.

Comment: For the selector you would need the argument as well - `pollingRatesApi.endpoints.getRates.select(params)(state)`